# Search string in a list and delete lists which don't have it entirely

Tags: python

I have a variable (x) which has multiple lists under it. Last item of the list is referencing the first item in the lists. (e.g list which has a last item value of '1' is compatible with a list where its first item value is '1')

```
['1', 'test', '3']
['2', 'test2', '1']
['3', 'test3', '4']
['4', 'test4', '3']
```

How could I first search for lists that have test2 in them, then search a list which is compatible with it and then delete every other list which isn't neither of these two.

Result should be the following:

```
['1', 'test', '3']
['2', 'test2', '1']
```

Haven't been able to figure the answer out at all. Also a place of concern is that 'test2' compatible list could be above it or under it (like it is in the case with 'test3 list).

Comment: I suppose `x` is a list of lists?

Comment: Do it in two steps: (1) collect all the triples that have `'test2'` in them. (2) collect all the lriplets that are compatible.

Comment: Is there only one `test2` list or multiple?

Comment: Better to avoid double negatives such as "isn't neither of these two" if you want people to understand your question. Or did you mean "isn't either ..."?

Comment: @oda There's multiple. In my mind the solution would've been that first I search for 'test2', if that is found I find the compatible list and then start searching for other lists with 'test2' where I left off.

Comment: @Damiaan Great question as I'm not very experienced in Python. Originally the file came in .txt and from that I made every line into a list with for loop and .split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

1. collect all the triples that have 'test2' in them;
2. collect all the triplets that are compatible.

```py
x = [
    ['1', 'test', '3'],
    ['2', 'test2', '1'],
    ['3', 'test3', '4'],
    ['4', 'test4', '3']
]

have_test2 = [t for t in x if t[1] == 'test2']
compatible_numbers = {n for (_,_,n) in have_test2}
are_compatible = [t for t in x if t[0] in compatible_numbers]
print(have_test2, are_compatible)
# [['2', 'test2', '1']] [['1', 'test', '3']]
```

Or slightly more direct:

```py
x = ...

compatible_numbers = {n for (_,test,n) in x if test == 'test2'}
all_results = [t for t in x if t[1] == 'test2' or t[0] in compatible_numbers]

print(all_results)
# [['1', 'test', '3'], ['2', 'test2', '1']]
```

**Important note**

You might notice that I used curly brackets `{ }` when defining `compatible_numbers`. This notation defines a `set` rather than a `list`. `set` are a slightly different data structure than lists, and they are particularly efficient when there is a need to test membership. The membership test `if t[0] in compatible_numbers` is fast because `compatible_numbers` is a set; it would be slow if `compatible_numbers` was a list.

Note that `set` here is the name of a python data structure. It is a relatively standard name for similar structures in other programming languages. This data structure shares its name with the mathematical objects "set". This shared name is not a coincidence, but still, programming sets and mathematical sets are not the same thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
x = [
['1', 'test', '3'],
['2', 'test2', '1'],
['3', 'test3', '4'],
['4', 'test4', '3']]
output = []
for sub_list in x:
    if sub_list[1] == "test2":
        compatible = int(sub_list[2])
        output.append(sub_list)
output+=[y for y in x if y[0] is compatible]
```